# Sorting with Comparator - Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, java-8

I am trying to sort `CalculationModelDetails` in `Asc` and if `priceRange (getPriceRange() == null)` it is placed last of a sorted list ..

I encounter a null pointer exception here `Comparator.comparing(CalculationModelDetail::getPriceRange, (s1, s2) -> s2.compareTo(s1));`

when I run the test ..

Could you let me know what am I missing here ..

```
     public class PriceList extends ArrayList<Price> {
        public static int compare(Price p1, Price p2) {
                return p1.getAmount().compareTo(p2.getAmount());
            }
        }
```

---

```
    public class PriceRange { 
    
        private final Price minimum;
    
        private final Price maximum;
    
    public int compareTo(PriceRange that) {
            Comparator<PriceRange> rangeComparator = Comparator
                    .comparing((PriceRange priceRange) -> priceRange.getMinimum(), (s1, s2) -> PriceList.compare(s1, s2))
                    .thenComparing((PriceRange priceRange) -> priceRange.getMaximum(), (s1, s2) -> PriceList.compare(s1, s2));
            return rangeComparator.compare(this, that);
        }
    }
```

---

```
    public class CalculationModelDetail {
        private BigDecimal perCent;
        private Price absolute;
        private PriceRange priceRange;
    ...
    }
```

---

```
    public class CalculationModelDetailList extends ArrayList<CalculationModelDetail> {
        public List<CalculationModelDetail> sort() {
            Comparator<CalculationModelDetail> detailComparator
                    = Comparator.comparing(CalculationModelDetail::getPriceRange, (s1, s2) -> s2.compareTo(s1));
            Comparator<CalculationModelDetail> detailComparator_nullLast = Comparator.nullsLast(detailComparator);
            Collections.sort(this , detailComparator_nullLast);
            return this;
        }
    }
```

---

```
    @Test
        public final void testSort() {
            final CalculationModelDetailList list = new CalculationModelDetailList();
    
            final CalculationModelDetail detail0 = new CalculationModelDetail();
            list.add(detail0);
            detail0.setPriceRange(null);
    
            final CalculationModelDetail detail1 = new CalculationModelDetail();
            list.add(detail1);
            detail1.setPriceRange(new PriceRange(1, 9));
    
            final CalculationModelDetail detail2 = new CalculationModelDetail();
            list.add(detail2);
            detail2.setPriceRange(new PriceRange(10, 19));
    
            final CalculationModelDetail detail3 = new CalculationModelDetail();
            list.add(detail3);
            detail3.setPriceRange(new PriceRange(20, 29));
    
            final CalculationModelDetail detail4 = new CalculationModelDetail();
            list.add(detail4);
            detail4.setPriceRange(null);
    
            List<CalculationModelDetail> actual = list.sort();
    
    
        }
```

---

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
> com.acc.CalculationModelDetailList.lambda$sort$1(CalculationModelDetailList.java:48)
> at
> java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$ea9a8b3a$1(Comparator.java:436)
> at java.util.Comparators$NullComparator.compare(Comparators.java:83)
> at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `priceRange` as null in `detail0` so while sorting when you are getting the `priceRange` value, you are calling `compareTo` method on a null reference. Hence the issue.
You need to handle this null value in `detailComparator`.

```
class CalculationModelDetailList extends ArrayList<CalculationModelDetail> {

    public List<CalculationModelDetail> sort() {
        Comparator<CalculationModelDetail> detailComparator = Comparator.comparing(
                CalculationModelDetail::getPriceRange,
                Comparator.nullsLast((s1, s2) -> s2.compareTo(s1)));
        Comparator<CalculationModelDetail> detailComparator_nullLast = Comparator
                .nullsLast(detailComparator);
        Collections.sort(this, detailComparator_nullLast);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: but isnt that supposed to be handled by Comparator.nullsLast

Comment: I need to sort these in Asc order of priceRange  and place the nulls (calculationModelDetail.getPriceRange() == null ) in the end of the sorted list ..

Comment: @ArdentJavaLearner : but the detailComparator is also receiving null values right.. so those values will have to be handled. You don't want to set a sorting order here then you may just return any int in case s1 or s2 is null. If both values are available only then go for compareTo.

Comment: @ArdentJavaLearner : To avoid the null checks apply `Comparator.nullsLast` when comparing `PriceRange` `s1` and `s2` as well..!!